# Database Error: The transaction was overridden by a subsequent set how to solve

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know this is a common error and there are many threads in SO. But nothing helped me.

Here is my problem:

My DB structure:
    root
        /posts/
        /user-posts/userId/

Each post has few attributes including:
    likeCount
    likes > id : true

Whenever a post is created, it is stored in both /posts/ and /user-posts/ node. But when I likes the post, it updates in one and fails in another with the error mentioned in Question title.

Code used for inserting a post in firebase DB:

```
Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, feedValues);
childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, feedValues);
dbRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

Code used for like:

```
public static void updateLikeInServer(DatabaseReference dbRef, final String userId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "updateLikeInServer:started:");
    dbRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Post post = mutableData.getValue(Post.class);
            if (post == null) {  // It comes as null for /user-posts/ but not for /posts/
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            if (post.getLikes().containsKey(userId)) {
                post.setLikesCount(post.getLikesCount() - 1);
                post.getLikes().remove(userId);
            } else {
                post.setLikesCount(post.getLikesCount() + 1);
                post.getLikes().put(userId, true);
            }

            // Set value and report transaction success
            mutableData.setValue(post);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "updateLikeInServer:onComplete: " + databaseError);
        }
    });
}
```

Since the like count need to be updated in both /user-posts/ and /posts/, I am calling the above method twice with corresponding DatabaseReference.

**Arguments**:

1. If it fails, it should fail for both the nodes /user-posts/ and /posts/. Why it's not failing for both locations?
2. It only fails only for 1st time like, but if you do it consecutively like > dislike > like > dislike, it succeeds for both locations from 2nd time on wards. Why so?
3. **MOST IMPORTANT**: The error comes only when I like the post created by friend. If I like my own post, no error.

Comment: In my case. I have registered 2 google accounts on my phone. Then I switched accounts within my app, Then this error started coming up on one of my counter(using transaction also).
But your workaround by calling twice worked. Weird thing right?

Comment: Its weird and moreover seems like a bug to me. May be clarified by Firebase team.

Answer (score -1):

Got rid of the problem with below workaround. Don't know whether this is the proper way or not, but would love to know from others if any better solution is there.

Since it only happens for 1st time transaction, I am trying to check the error and retry the same operation again which succeeds in the 2nd attempt.

```
@Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "updateLikeInServer:onComplete: " + databaseError);
            if (databaseError != null && databaseError.getCode() == DatabaseError.OVERRIDDEN_BY_SET) {
                // Retry the same
                updateLikeInServer(dbRef, userId);
            }
        }
```

The above snippet fixed my problem. But I would love to listen best answer if possible.

Comment: I don't know who -1ed it. But probably would love to listen the better solution. Because, I know this is not a good solution and am still finding the correct one.